# Installing conda packages in specific directory

Tags: python, conda, miniconda, anaconda3

Is there any way to download and install the conda packages in specified directory without creating a conda environment in that directory?

Comment: You can always download an archive of the package from `https://anaconda.org/` and extract it in any folder you like. Not sure whether it makes sense to call this  `install the conda packages in specified directory` though. After all installing is integrating into an existing structure and conda packages make most sense inside the structure of a conda environment. Maybe it would make sense to elaborate a bit on your use case to help us giving better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to download the packages, you can set an environmental variable to the specified directory, and use the --download-only switch

```
set CONDA_PKGS_DIRS=C:\temp

conda install zlib --download-only

dir c:\temp\
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is DC83-883D

 Directory of c:\temp

...
07/13/2020  08:16 PM    <DIR>          zlib-1.2.11-h2fa13f4_1006
07/13/2020  08:16 PM           241,593 zlib-1.2.11-h2fa13f4_1006.tar.bz2
```

Comment: you're welcome! Hope this helps with your case. I had to do this previously, to create a local repository for users with no access to the internet or blocked by a firewall.

Comment: Yes. After exporting this env, do I need to export PYTHONPATH to the specified CONDA_PKGS_DIRS?

Comment: Yes, if you want to use those packages in a python script, you will need to add the directory to your PATH and/or PYTHONPATH environment variables to access them. Reference: https://www.devdungeon.com/content/python-import-syspath-and-pythonpath-tutorial